Azure Pipeline: Unable to pass templates through two other templates
I have 2 template files that I am passing to another (stage) template (file: build-and-deploy.yml) that's in another repo (repoB) and I am doing this from azure-pipeline.yml which is in repoA. Once in repoB, depending on the option selected during the pipeline run, build-and-deploy.yml will call two other (stage) templates 0.yml or 1.yml. Unless I hard code the 2 templates in build-and-deploy.yml, I am unable to achieve this. The
azure-pipeline.yml (in repoA):
extends:
  template: templates/build-and-deploy.yml@repoB
  parameters:
    buildJobs:
      - template: pipeline/build.yml
      - template: pipeline/static-scans.yml

As you can see it extends to repoB, and it passed two templates pipeline/build.yml and pipeline/static-scans.yml. In repoB, depending on a parameter selected, it will either call two stage files 1.yml or 2.yml
build-and-deploy.yml (in repoB)
stages:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.trunkFlow, true) }}:
    - template: deployment-types/0.yml
      parameters:
        allowDevDeployment: ${{ parameters.allowDevDeployment }}
        buildJobs:
        - template: ${{ parameters.buildJobs }} // THIS DOES NOT WORK
        devJobs:
        - template: ${{ parameters.devJobs }} // THIS DOES NOT WORK
          parameters:
            environment: Dev
            location: WestUS
        ...

  - ${{ else }}:
    - template: deployment-types/0.yml
      parameters:
        allowDevDeployment: ${{ parameters.allowDevDeployment }}
        serviceEmail: $(platformAdoGroup)
        buildJobs:
        - template: ${{ parameters.buildJobs }} // THIS DOES NOT WORK
        devJobs:
        - template: ${{ parameters.devJobs }} // THIS DOES NOT WORK
          parameters:
            environment: Dev
            location: WestUS
        ...

on 0.yml (also in repoB, and also a stage template/file):
stages:
- ${{ if gt(length(parameters.buildJobs), 0) }}:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    - ${{ each job in parameters.buildJobs }}:
      - ${{ if startsWith(job.pool.vmImage, 'ubuntu') }}:
        - job: ${{ job.job }}
          pool: ${{ job.pool }}
          ${{ if job.condition }}:
            condition: ${{ job.condition }}
          ${{ if job.dependsOn }}:
          ...
- ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop'), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/support/'), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/feature/')) }}:
  - ${{ if gt(length(parameters.devTestJobs), 0) }}:
    - stage: DevTest
      ${{ if ne(parameters.devTestStageLabel, 'none') }}:
        displayName: ${{ parameters.devTestStageLabel }}
      jobs:
      - ${{ parameters.devTestJobs }}

  - ${{ if ne(parameters.acunetixWebsite, 'none') }}:
    - stage: AcunetixOnDevTest
      dependsOn: ${{ parameters.acunetixDependsOn }}
      jobs:
      - template: ../scanning/acunetix.yml
  ...

in 1.yml (also in repoB, and also a stage template/file): Just imagine as 0.yml, with only changes to the branching strategy.
This is the error:

/templates/build-and-deploy.yml@repoB: Unexpected type 'SequenceToken' encountered while reading 'template reference path'. The type 'LiteralToken' was expected.



Please follow the 2nd part from Rui's answer for a check. If the issue persists, please also share pipeline/build.yml content, and clarify parameters.buildJobs is defined as jobList type?

For other jobs like devJobs (for the dev stage) and devTestJobs for the devtest stage, if they are also defined as jobList type, you cannot pass parameter together, could consider variable instead, but it depends on more details on your content.

@wadezhou-MSFT - You're right. The other jobs are also jobLists. So how may I pass them in a variable? The thing is I need to avoid modifying azure-pipeline.yml at any cost. So essentially the request is that keeping the current setting in azure-pipeline.yml, I'd like to be able to pass a list of jobs to another template, and through it, to another stage template. What info would you like from me?

You need to transfer the other jobs like buildjob, but for the parameters like environment, location, you can define directly in build-and-deploy.yml, but invoke them as $(var) in 0.yml, and 1.yml. When you edit the main pipeline in repoA, on top right, you can validate the yaml, and download the full yaml. With the full  yaml, you can see the expanded jobs/tasks which is the real one. If you have any queires, you can raise a new ticket with more details in 0.yml, show where/how is the environment, location parameter used.

Referencing templates from the local repository
If build.yml and static-scans.yml templates are NOT in the remote repository repoB, you need to use @self to reference local templates  (see example in Use other repositories)
extends:
  template: templates/build-and-deploy.yml@repoB # <---------- use remote template from repoB repository
  parameters:
    buildJobs:
      - template: pipeline/build.yml@self         # <---------- use template from local repository 
      - template: pipeline/static-scans.yml@self  # <---------- use template from local repository

Using parameters with type jobList
You're not showing the parameters in build-and-deploy.yml template (in repoB), but I'll assume buildJobs has type jobList - so you should use it like this:
parameters:
  - name: trunkFlow
    type: boolean

  - name: allowDevDeployment
    type: boolean

  - name: buildJobs
    type: jobList
  
  # other parameters here

stages:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.trunkFlow, true) }}:
    - template: deployment-types/0.yml
      parameters:
        allowDevDeployment: ${{ parameters.allowDevDeployment }}
        buildJobs: ${{ parameters.buildJobs }} # assuming buildJobs in template deployment-types/0.yml is of type jobList
        # ...


Oh, I need to declare self in azure-pipeline.yml, OK let me try that.

Unfortunely, it hasn't worked. I have updated my post with the error screenshot. It's the same as before, just that I had forgotten to mention it.

@AnonymousPerson check the second part of my answer.

Thanks, this is fine for the buildjob, ie, but there are other jobs that I pass, like devJobs (for the dev stage) and devTestJobs for the devtest stage etc, and these have parameters (of env and location for instance). How can I pass that?

@AnonymousPerson one step at a time - start by commenting out some templates and fix the compilation errors. And please edit your question and include the list of parameters for each template.

Maybe a new ticket with the yaml detail can track for the other jobs better. The buildjob issue is resolved with correct format.

@AnonymousPerson I agree with Wade - it seems there are a few different issues to fix, so it's probably better to post a new question. Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer regarding the issues I mentioned.

Guys, very sorry I couldn't reply. I will try your suggestions and get back. Some priority work came about and I was called in. Give me a days' time.

@AnonymousPerson did you have the opportunity to try what I suggested?

Hello @RuiJarimba - I decided to abandon my approach, and simply call 1.yml directly from azure-pipeline.yml
Thanks for looking into it.

@AnonymousPerson, you can post an answer yourself, so that other can also benefit from it. Thanks.

@wadezhou-MSFT - sorry for the late response. The team decided to scrap the idea of having two branching strategies, so I've abandoned this. Thank you all for your valuable insights.
